# Display post only for specific category

Tags: php, wordpress

I am very newbie into wordpress development so i had face a issue for displaying some post for specific category...

Like, I am adding(posting) some images into database for post_picture category...

Now at front end i have a page name Picture Mania where i just want to display only those image which i added into post_picture category...

For this purpose first i installed the [php-exec plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/exec-php/) , and now I am trying to retrieve my desire category images on that page by this code

```
<?php query_posts('post_picture =post_picture&showposts=5');
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  // do whatever you want
?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
                <?php cup_post_nav(); ?>
                <?php comments_template(); ?>
<b><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php
endwhile;
?>
```

It working fine, but displaying all category images, so conclusion I am not getting my desire output...

Answer will be much appreciated....and thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass **category id** (cat=3) such as

```
<?php query_posts('cat=3&showposts=5');
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  // do whatever you want
?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
                <?php cup_post_nav(); ?>
                <?php comments_template(); ?>
<b><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php
endwhile;
?>
```

Or you can use **category name** in arary as well:

```
query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'my-category-slug', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
```

query_post Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Although [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) is recommended approach instead of query_posts

Answer (score 1):

for showing posts of specific category, you could add `cat=YOUR_CATEGORY_ID` in `query_posts()` like:

```
query_posts('post_picture=post_picture&showposts=5&cat=$your_Category_Id');
```

as in [query_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) example

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=your-post_picture-category-id&showposts=5');

while (have_posts()) : the_post();
// do whatever you want
?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
<?php cup_post_nav(); ?>
<?php comments_template(); ?>
<b><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"> 
<?php the_title(); ?></a>
```